# Best books for General and Advanced Statistical Data Analysis and Modeling

Tags: references

I would like to know which are your favourite books on **General** and **Advanced** Statistical Data Analysis and Modeling.

In particular, I would like to know which books you consider the **must-have** for an applied statistician, like "Econometric Analysis" (Greene) and "Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data" (Woolridge) are for econometricians.

Comment: What do you mean by advanced?

Comment: I mean: advanced $\neq$ introductory.

Comment: So it could be any specialised statistical handbook?

Comment: Yes, for example if you can suggest a book on survival analysis, it would be really appreciated!

Comment: This makes possibly *any* non-introductory book meet the criteria (in Amazon there is $\approx 5000$ books on query "advanced statistics"). You should make it more specific e.g. "books on survival analysis". I vote o close this as **too broad**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are no-brainers:

- Elements of statistical learning by Hastie, Tibshirani and Friedman: http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/
- Pattern recognition and machine learning by Bishop: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/people/cmbishop/#!prml-book

Perhaps someone could recommend the default answer for statistical books on multivariate data analysis?

Answer (score 4):

*The* book on Bayesian data analysis:

The Bayesian Choice by Christian Robert. http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387952314

While *the* book on machine learning and big data would be, as Tommy L said:

Elements of statistical learning by Hastie, Tibshirani and Friedman. http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/